# SQL: Finding Integers between columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, integer

I'm having trouble with the following situation: I have data for multiple schools, so each school has a school ID number (SchlID). They also have a high and low grade column for each class that is offered (LoGrd) and (HiGrd). I need to know the grades that are offered at each school based on all the classes. 
For example, School 707 offers a class with LoGrd 6 and HiGrd 6 (meaning only 6th graders attend). They also offer a class with LoGrd 6 and HiGrd 8 (meaning that 6th, 7th and 8th graders attend this class). On the other hand, School 710 offers the class with logrd 9 and higrd 12. So I want the output to have on column for school and a list of the grades that school offers with one grade per row, like below

- SchlID Grade
- 707    6
- 707    7
- 707    8
- 710    9
- 710    10
- 710    11
- 710    12

Thank you!

Comment: Along with the problem you should **include the code you have up until this point** (*make some effort to answer your problem/question as Stack Overflow is not a code writing service*). Please also include a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also read [How do I ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Try searching for _numbers table_ or _tally table_ and you'll likely find some applicable information.

Answer (score 0):

Below is some code that does what you need. We use a recursive CTE to generate a list of all possible grades. In this case it is 1 to 15 which should be sufficient for your case. Then we join it to the school table to select all grades between LoGrd and HiGrd.

```
CREATE TABLE school (SchID INT,LoGrd INT,HiGrd INT);
INSERT INTO school VALUES (707,6,9);
INSERT INTO school VALUES (710,10,12);

WITH AllPossibleGrades (N) AS (
    SELECT 1 AS N
    UNION ALL
    SELECT R.N+1 AS N
    FROM AllPossibleGrades R
    WHERE R.N<=15
)
SELECT S.SchID,AG.N AS Grade
FROM school S
     INNER JOIN AllPossibleGrades AG ON AG.N>=S.LoGrd AND AG.N<=S.HiGrd;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I added in the Distinct command at the end (SELECT DISTINCT S.SchID, Ag.N AS Grade) so it would give me only unique grades offered since it's not important how many of one grade there are, just what grades are being taught at the school. I appreciate your help!!!